# Postgres - Update and restructure attribute of JSONB type colum

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a table which has a column named "data" of type JSONB. I am trying to create a migration script based on the recent model changes. (postgres 9.4)

**"gstNotRegisteredReason","gstRegistered","isIndiaGSTComposition"**
in old model needs to be changed as    **"vatExemptionReason","vatExemption","auxiliaryProperties"** in the new model.

Old Model:

```
 {  
   "requestId":531956,
   "requestVersion":5,
   "supplier":{  
      "taxClassificationId":null,
      "supplierScid":null,
      "gstNotRegisteredReason":null,      (boolean)
      "gstRegistered":null,               (boolean)
      "isIndiaGSTComposition":true        (boolean)
   },
   "createTime":"2017-07-17T06:48:52",    
}
```

New Model:

```
 {        
   "requestId":531956,
   "requestVersion":5,
   "supplier":{  
      "taxClassificationId":null,
      "supplierScid":null,
      "vatExemptionReason":null,         (boolean)
      "vatExemption":null,               (boolean)
      "AuxiliaryProperties":[
                   {
                    "id":"indiaGSTComposition",
                    "booleanValue":true
                    }
                  ]           
   },      
   "createTime":"2017-07-17T06:48:52",     
}
```

I came up with this query

```
update requests set data=regexp_replace(data::text, '"gstRegistered": ', '"vatExemption":', 'g')::jsonb;
update requests set data=regexp_replace(data::text, '"gstNotRegisteredReason": ', '"vatExemptionReason":', 'g')::jsonb;
```

But i am not sure how to convert isIndiaGSTComposition(boolean) to auxiliaryProperties(Array).

Please note that, if isIndiaGSTComposition is null, it should be auxiliaryProperties : null. But if it has true or false, it needs to be in the above data structure format(like in "new model" example above).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

**Postgres 9.4**:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=50fb8c1459ef47ea71df05900050ba0f)

With that version you could do this with the `regexp_replace` function as well:

```
UPDATE 
    requests
SET data =  
        regexp_replace(
            data::text,
            '"india"[\s]*:[\s]*(true|false|null)',                              -- A
            '"aux":' || CASE  
                            WHEN (data -> 'india')::text = 'null' THEN 'null'   -- B 
                            ELSE '[{"id":"india", "booleanValue":' || (data -> 'india')::text || '}]' -- C
                        END, 
            'g'
        )::jsonb;
```

A: Finding the whole `india` key/value pair. With `[\s]*` it is possible to act with the whitespaces if there are different formats.

B/C: Replace with the string `'"aux":something'`. "Something" is build by a `CASE` clause: If `india` has the string `'null'` then give `'null'` (B). Otherwise take the json array string with the origin `india` value (C).

(I was wondering why are you needing an array for the `aux` value...)

---

**Postgres 9.6+**

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2f1864eef1abba0c872f0e65a071c65c)

This version comes with a better json support so the problem can be solved without the text casts and regexp clauses - speaking in a more json-like way.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html

```
UPDATE 
    requests
SET 
    data = jsonb_insert(                                      -- A
               data - 'india',                                -- B
               '{aux}',                                       -- C
               CASE                                           -- D
                   WHEN data -> 'india' = 'null' THEN 'null'
                   ELSE jsonb_insert(                         -- E
                            '[{"id":"india"}]'::jsonb,        -- F
                            '{0, booleanValue}',              -- G
                            data -> 'india'                   -- H
                   ) 
               END
            );
```

A: `jsonb_insert` inserts a new element into a given json element:

B: First parameter of the function is the json to put the new object in. Here I am taking the data object but removing the `india` element before.

C: Second parameter - the path where to insert the new element: The new json object will be inserted as value of the key `"aux"`. If it does not exist (as in our case) it will be created.

D: Third parameter - the element to be inserted: Creating a new element. The `CASE` clause logic is similar to the version above. If the `india` value is `'null'` then give `'null'`. Otherwise:

E: Creating a new json element and inserting the old `india` value

F: The new element is the static json array `'[{"id":"india"}]'`.

G: This is a path: Taking the first element (`"0"`) and then insert the new object into `"booleanValue"`. Create this key if it does not exist.

H: Taking the old `india` value. The resulting element could be `[{"id":"india", "booelanValue: true"}]`. This is taken as value for the `"aux"` element in (C)